# Get (conditional) value(s) of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm new to .JS and I'm working with code I didn't write originally. I need to get the value of some radio buttons once a conditional selection has been made.

The conditional part relates to the need for transportation. If the user needs transportation, a new set of radio buttons are presented with bus route options. These are the values I need returned by the form.

**The HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Transportation Registration</legend>
<div class="col3">
    <div class="checklabel">Transportation needs</div>
    <ul class="checkwrap">
        <li>
            <input name="transportation" type="radio" id="transportation-none" value="None" checked="checked" data-price="0" data-deposit="0" />
            <label for="transportation-none">None</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input name="transportation" type="radio" id="transportation-am_only" value="AM Only" data-price="60" data-deposit="50" />
            <label for="transportation-am_only">AM Only</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input name="transportation" type="radio" id="transportation-pm_only" value="PM Only" data-price="60" data-deposit="50" />
            <label for="transportation-pm_only">PM Only</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input name="transportation" type="radio" id="transportation-round_trip" value="Both AM & PM" data-price="100" data-deposit="50" />
            <label for="transportation-round_trip">Round-Trip</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div align="center"><p><strong>One-Way (AM or PM): $60/week | Round-Trip: $100/week</strong></p></div>                                                 
<div>
    <div class="checklabel">Bus Route 1:</div>
    <ul class="checkwrap">
        <li><input name="busroute" type="radio" id="bus_1" value="Bus 1" class="required" /><label for="bus_1">Bus 1</label></li>
        <li><input name="busroute" type="radio" id="bus_2" value="Bus 2" class="required" /><label for="bus_2">Bus 2</label></li>
        <li><input name="busroute" type="radio" id="bus_3" value="Bus 3" class="required" /><label for="bus_3">Bus 3</label></li>
        <li><input name="busroute" type="radio" id="bus_4" value="Bus 4" class="required" /><label for="bus_4">Bus 4</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**And the (incomplete?) .JS:**

```
function transportation() {
if($('#transportation-none').is(':checked')) {
    $('[name=busroute]')
        .removeClass("required")
        .val('')
            .closest('div')
            .hide();
} else {
    $('[name=busroute]')
        .addClass("required")
            .closest('div')
            .show();
}
}
```

I'm hoping this makes sense. The page contains many more functions but I think I'm calling out the section that needs to be fixed. I may need to provide more code to get an answer.

Comment: Well your code execute only on page load (aka when the js script is loaded) you would probably need to bind your function `transportation()` to an event on the radio buttons. (`onclick=""` might be helpful if you want to keep it simple).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your function, but, from what you've shown, you never call it. You can use jQuery to bind this function call to any change event from the transportation radio inputs:

```
$('input[name="transportation"]').on('change', transportation);
```